# Erlang functions/library to sanitize web input?

Tags: erlang, xss

I like to prevent XSS on my project, i just use Erlang and nginx.
Are there some libraries for this?

Is there an alternative i didn't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look the escape function in [mochiweb_html](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_html.erl), you could use this as a starting point.

I'm not aware of any erlang library intended for this specifically and this is something that tends to be implemented [half way/wrong](http://wonko.com/post/html-escaping) by most libraries (including Mochiweb.)

Comment: Thanks for the library and the article is very insightful.